# How do I change the $PATH so I can launch Sublime Text from the command line?

Tags: path, sublimetext3

Currently when I type `echo $PATH` the below appears:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin`

I deleted mongodb, but this path shows up.  I don't know how to get rid of that. 
 How do I get to the place where I can type:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/sublime
```

Per Colt Steele's class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can type in your `ln` command directly into Terminal where you typed the `echo` command. The components in your `$PATH` (not `$SPATH`) are separated by colons (`:`), and if you look at the results you'll see that `/usr/local/bin` is already there, so you don't need to alter the path. Don't worry about the mongodb setting, it's not hurting anything.

Please note that in order to run that `ln` command, you'll need to use [`sudo`](https://ss64.com/osx/sudo.html):

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/sublime
```

and type in your administrator password, as `/usr/local/bin` is a protected directory.

Once you've done all this, you'll be able to open a file in Sublime from Terminal by typing

`sublime filename`